# feed dialog message dosen't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm publishing a message on user wall using Facebook's "Post to your wall" popup. It shows a text area where the user can write a message. I want to put custom text in that text area; right now it has a watermark that says "write something...". I need to replace that.

I'm using this code which same from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/:

```
FB.init({ 
        appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });

     FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
        message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    message: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  });
```

Add link

Comment: I want to put message in textarea not description.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It seems that I had to give up the idea.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this facebook platform update](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/), since July 12 the *message* field is no longer supported.